# Remove textNode with mouseout DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've created a button that displays a box when clicked, then on mouseover the class of the box (which is boxCount) appears as text. Now, I want to remove this text on mouseout. I've tried countless options and I can't seem to get it. My prior attempts are commented out.

I've also tried variations on 'removeChild'. Below is a snippet of my code, but here is a link to [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/tajihebaji/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
    function addBox() {
        let box = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(box);
        box.className = 'box';

        let boxText = document.createTextNode(boxCount);
        boxText = boxCount++;
        boxText.className = 'boxText';

        box.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            box.append(boxText);
        });

        box.addEventListener('mouseout', disappear());

        function disappear() {
                console.log('worked');
                // boxText = "";

                // let newText =document.getElementsByClassName('box');
                // newText = " ";
                // box.append(newText);

                // document.getElementById('box').style.display="none";

                // let boxText = document.createTextNode("");
                // box.appendChild(boxText);
                // boxText.parentNode.removeChild(boxText);

                // boxCount.nodeValue = '';

                // var boxText = document.createElement('p');
                // boxText.textContent = "";
                // box.append(boxText); 
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove ( ) from 'disappear' call to define listener method correctly and set the box content with void string

```
 .....

 box.addEventListener('mouseout', disappear);

 function disappear() {             
    box.innerHTML = "";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the child node and remove it from parent where text node can get using [`Node#childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property and remove it from DOM using [`Node#removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) method or simply use [`ChildNode#remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) method to remove the node.

```
box.childNodes[0].remove();

// or
box.removeChild(box.childNodes[0])
```

---

Two more things adding `className` property to a textNode doesn't make any change(which doesn't make any sense) and when you are binding `mouseout` event handler use function reference don't use it like `disappear()` which calls and set return value as callback.

```
box.addEventListener('mouseout', disappear);
// remove parentheses -------------------^^--
```

---

```js
let container = document.body;

let box = document.createElement('div');
container.appendChild(box);
box.className = 'box';

let boxText = document.createTextNode(1);


box.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  box.append(boxText);
});

box.addEventListener('mouseout', disappear);

function disappear() {
  console.log('worked');
  box.childNodes[0].remove();
  //box.removeChild(box.childNodes[0])
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
```